# probability of a dart hitting a radius $\leq 2$ from the center given the joint distribution of $(x,y)$ .

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've got the following question in probability:

A man throws a dart at a dart board. If the point which dart hits is $(x,y)$, then the joint PDF of $(x,y)$ is given by,

$$f_{XY}(x,y|x_0,y_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}exp\{ -\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2} - \frac{(y - y_0)^2}{2}\} $$

Where $(x_0,y_0)$ is the target that the man is aiming at. In this case the man is aiming at the middle of the board with coordinates $(3,2)$. i.e., $x_0 = 3$ and $y_0 = 2$ for our case. The first circle of the dart board has a radius of $r=2$.

If the man throws 10 darts. What is the probability that he hits at least one dart inside the first circle?

Okay, basically what it asks is $Pr((x-3)^2+(y-2)^2 \leq 2^2)$. Assuming $x$ is given, this probability can be shown as,

$$Pr(2-\sqrt{2^2 - (x-3)^2} \leq y \leq 2+\sqrt{2^2 - (x-3)^2})$$

so what I have to find is,

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{2\pi}exp\{ -\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2} - \frac{(y - y_0)^2}{2}\}dydx}$$

where $a = 2-\sqrt{2^2 - (x-3)^2}$ and $b = 2+\sqrt{2^2 - (x-3)^2}$.

I already know my approach is wrong by now. This form is intractable. But I'm stuck here without knowing what to do. I've noticed that $x$ and $y$ are independent normal distributions. But I don't know where to do with that knowledge. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Rayleigh distribution may helps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use polar coordinates.  $r^2=(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2$.

Then the probability of one dart ending up inside the circle is

$$q=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^2e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}2\pi r dr=(1-\frac{1}{e^2})$$

The probability of no hits in any of the 10 throws is $(1-q)^{10}$. So the probability of at least 1 hit is $$1-(1-q)^{10}$$